# how can I save a record by inserting values from a new window?

Tags: apex, controller

This is my visual force page:

```
<apex:page Controller="saveRecordFromWindow" id="page">
<script>

    function openWindow()
    {

          var myWindow = window.open( "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");
          myWindow.document.write("<Form onsubmit='CallApexMethod()'>LastName<input type = 'text' name ='n'><input type = 'Submit'></form>");

    }

</script>
<apex:form id="form">
<apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" id="call" action="{!myActionInController}"/>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb" title="Open a new Window">

            <apex:pageblockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Go to Window" onclick="openWindow()" />
            </apex:pageblockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class saveRecordFromWindow

{

public PageReference myActionInController() {
    return null;
}


  public Contact con{get;set;}


  public void myActionInController(String name)
  {
      con = NEW Contact();
      con.LastName = name;
  }
}
```

Here I am not getting how to pass reference from that VF page to class.

Comment: Please explore apex:param that will help you. you need to add one parameter in apex:function.
User below code to get param value in apex : 
String lastName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('lastname');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can call a function with parameter from VF to your custom controller. I prefer using the remoteAction, but you can achieve this by using get and set methods as well. A naive implementation would look something like this:

In your controller:

```
@remoteAction
public static void myActionInController(String myParameter) {

  con = NEW Contact();
  con.LastName = myParameter;

  insert con;    
}
```

In your visual force:

```
 <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" id="call" action="{!myActionInController}"/>
        <apex:param name="theParameter" value="{!myParameter}" 
 </apex:actionFunction>
```

I hope this makes sense.